# How to update any attribute in core data in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have read many problems that relate to my problem. I almost try all of the solution but it still not working.

My problem is I want to update an existing object in my core data named "Person"

Here is my code:

```
func updateDataToCoreData() -> Void {
     var people : [Person]()
    // 1
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    // 2
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")

    // 3
    var err : NSError?
    let fetchedResults = managedContext?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &err) as? [Person]

    if let result = fetchedResults {
        people = result

        for index in 0...people.count-1 {
            if people[index].valueForKey("code") as! String == id.text {
                var entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext!)
                let batchUpdate = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entity: entity!)
                batchUpdate.resultType = NSBatchUpdateRequestResultType.UpdatedObjectIDsResultType
                batchUpdate.propertiesToUpdate = ["name":"myUpdate"]
                var err : NSError?
                managedContext?.executeRequest(batchUpdate, error: &err)
                if let err = err {
                    println("Error \(err), \(err.userInfo)")
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        println("cannot fetch data from core data \(err), \(err!.userInfo)")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(people[index] as! Person).attribute = //set to new value
managedContext.save(nil)
```

Comment: add this code to which block? And please write the full source code because i'm new with Core Data

Comment: anywhere you'd like... depends on when you want the save to happen(i.e. whereEver the value change occurs)...ideally, make `appDelegate` and `managedContext` Global vars.